# Garbage values in vector of structs C++

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I am trying to use vector of structs for my need, and was writing some sample test code to understand the behavior. Below is the test code I have written:

### test.h

```
struct Student {
  char *name;
  int id;
  char *section;
};
typedef struct Student student_t;
```

### test.cc

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "test.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
  vector<student_t> vst;
  //vst.resize(2);
  student_t st;
  st.name = "student1";
  st.id = 4503;
  st.section = "secA";
  vst.push_back(st);
  vst.push_back({"student2", 4504, "secA"});
  for(auto const& s:vst) {
    std::cout<< " student: " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Name : " << s.name <<
        std::cout << " Id : " << s.id <<
        std::cout << " Section : " << s.section << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Output without specifying the size of the vector:

```
student: 
 Name : student10x6040c8 Id : 45030x6040c8 Section : secA
student: 
 Name : student20x6040c8 Id : 45040x6040c8 Section : secA
```

When resize(2) is used:

```
student: 
 Name :
```

I can't figure out the issue! Is there a problem with my initialization?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: With `resize` you actually *resizes* the vector. After the call it will be a vector of two default-constructed structures. When you then call `push_back` twice you *add* two more elements to the vector, making its size `4`. Printing out the first two default-constructed elements will of course give you unexpected results, as the pointers will be null-pointers. If you want to *reserve* space for two elements use [`reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) instead.

Comment: `typedef struct Student student_t;` is a Cism, as is using `char *` to store strings. To familiarise yourself with a more C++y style, you might want to grab a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465).

Comment: Thanks for your insights. I intend to share the structure file with some existing C code and that's the reason why I couldn't use a string in place of char *.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the code:

```
   std::cout << "Name : " << s.name <<
        std::cout << " Id : " << s.id <<
```

If you remove the line break, we obtain:

```
   std::cout << "Name : " << s.name << std::cout << " Id : " << s.id <<
```

Err, why are you trying to print `std::cout` on `std::cout`?  Either change the trailing `<<` to `;` or:

```
   std::cout << "Name : " << s.name
             << " Id : " << s.id
   ...
```

Aside:  You are storing up all *sorts* of trouble for yourself by making `name` and `section` be `char *`.  It works at the moment because you are setting them to string literals (which uses a deprecated conversion).  As soon as you try and make them variable, you will have to handle allocating and deallocating them.  Just save yourself all the grief and make them `std::string` and be happy.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize I was using << in place of ; even after looking at my code for a long time! Thanks for pointing out! :)

Comment: If you had stepped through with the debugger, you would have seen the call to `operator <<()` with `std::cout` as the argument - and at that point you would have kicked yourself.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple issues with your code. The primary one is that your're printing `std::cout` to `std::cout`. Your print expression has this (line breaks omitted to make it obvious):

```
std::cout << << "Name : " << s.name << std::cout
```

This is presumably not what you intended, and is what causes the numbers `0x6040c8` to appear in your output (it's probably the address of `std::cout`).

---

Another thing is your use of `resize`. If you use it, you will get a vector with two `Student` objects in it, which were default constructed. Since you don't provide a reasonable default constructor for your `Student` class, the values of its non-class members will be essentially random grarbage (and reading them is Undefined Behaviour).

The last issue is that your class has `char *` members without following the Rule of Three. This works in your example where the members are initialised from string literals (except you have `const` issues), but could break spectacularly if you later store some dynamically allocated memory in them.

The remedy for these two is one and the same: change the members to be of type `std::string`, which has both reasonable default initialisation and copy functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Code seems to be correct the thing I found weird is use of `char*` when you can use `std::string`

Also, the problem seems to be with the output i.e

```
std::cout << "Name : " << s.name <<
std::cout << " Id : " << s.id <<
std::cout << " Section : " << s.section << std::endl;
```

You're printing `std::cout` inside `std::cout` which is insane!

```
std::cout << "Name : " << s.name;
std::cout << " Id : " << s.id;
std::cout << " Section : " << s.section << std::endl;
```

You see, you missed the big time `;`. Welcome to C++!

I'd recommend you to start using debugger `gdb` if you are a Linux guy, I'll be a big-time help to such problems.